# Select2 / Selectize JS does not start domReady! - RequireJs

Tags: magento2, custom, select, requirejs-config.js

I have add my requirejs-config.js

> app/design/frontend/Altravista/my_theme/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    deps: [
        'js/custom'
    ],
    paths: {
        'select2': 'js/select2/select2.min'
    },
    shim: {
    'select2': {
      'deps': ['jquery']
           }
      }
};
```

I have my custom js file in

> app/design/frontend/Altravista/my_theme/web/js/custom.js

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "select2",
    "domReady!"
], 
function($, select2) {
        "use strict";
        $( function (){
            $('select').select2();
            console.log('my_log');
    });
});
```

but select2 does not start.

1. custom.js is loaded (I can see my log in console)
2. If i write jQuery('select').select2(); in console select2 works

PS: I have try also with selectize.js plugin and I have the same problem

if I use a scroll jquery event it works (start on scroll of page) so it is not a script error

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    // $('select').selectize({
 //     create: true,
 //     sortField: 'text'
    // });
    $('select').select2(
        { 
            width: 'resolve',
            closeOnSelect: true,
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1 
        }
    );
    console.log('Hey!');
    });
});
```

my custom.js file is loaded before select2.min.js

Comment: Vendor/Theme is your custom module?

Comment: is my custom theme

Comment: Could you please show me where you call your script ??

Comment: Does your select element rendered ??

Comment: The script is call in custom.js but select is not rendered

Answer (score 1):

I have solved with ko afterRender function:

Add afterRender="selectTwo()" to select template html

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/form/element/select.html

```
<select class="select select2" afterRender="selectTwo()" ...
```

add selectTwo function to js component

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/form/element/select.js

```
    selectTwo: function (){
        $('select.select2').select2();
    },
```